# can we run MoonBeam as solo chain instead of Para chain

Tags: polkadot, parachain, moonbeam, solo-chain

I have cloned the repo of [MoonBeam](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam.git) and run the chain as a "Development chain" but the chain is not producing blocks. Are there any reference links which i can follow to remove dependency from relay chain?

Answer (score 2):

Moonbeam is an implementation of Frontier, an Ethereum compatibility layer for Substrate. Frontier is a codebase managed by the team behind Moonbeam and Wei Tang. You need not fork Moonbeam's repository. Simply take advantage of Frontier.

Check it out here:

- https://paritytech.github.io/frontier/
- https://github.com/paritytech/frontier

Similar to the Basic Substrate Node template, there is a basic Frontier Substrate Node Template to start from which you will be able to produce blocks immediately:

- https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template

That being said, why will you not want to be a parachain? The economic security is significantly lesser starting out as a solochain (Orders of magnitude lesser). But if you are keen to try it out as a testnet, by all means be a solochain for now :)

Comment: A realistic reason. Small teams don't have enough backing assets to be a parachain(win the auction).

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Yeah that is a valid gap for very small budget teams. With parathreads and new potential ways to commit proof-of-validity blocks on the relay chain (Polkadot) in the future, the barrier for backing assets can come down dramatically.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier i need the consensus DPOS and EVM Compatibility with Unified accounts. That's why i wanted to implement MoonBeam para chain as Solo Chain.